# 'Taxes less subsidies' included in income approach of GDP

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

Why is 'taxes less subsidies' a part of the calculation of GDP (income approach)?

Is it because in the expenditure method of GDP, consumption expenditure will exceed those of the total "wages and profit of firms"?